# Talkback apk does not start

Tags: android, talkback

I built the google Talkback app from source.  However, it won't launch.  Also, I can't find it on the my Pixel 8 when I search for it by the name "Talkback".

Does anyone see why it's not launching and also isn't found when I search on the phone for the name "Talkback"?

Here's the steps I followed:

1. I downloaded the google Talkback source code from here: https://github.com/google/talkback.
2. I built the project and it created the file:

   ```
   ./build/outputs/apk/phone/release/talkback-phone-release-unsigned.apk
   ```
3. I deleted the original Talkback on my android phone via "adb uninstall com.android.talkback".  I confirmed that the original was deleted using the command because it no longer appears when I list packages:

   ```
   adb shell pm list packages | grep talk
   ```
4. I aligned my apk:

   ```
   zipalign -v -p 4 ./build/outputs/apk/phone/release/talkback-phone-release-unsigned.apk aligned/talkback-phone-release-unsigned-aligned.apk
   ```
5. I used a self signed cert to sign my Talkback apk:

   ```
   apksigner sign --ks release.keystore --out ./signed-apk/com.android.talkback.apk aligned/talkback-phone-release-unsigned-aligned.apk
   ```
6. I installed my apk and confirmed that it's there.

   ```
   adb shell pm list packages | grep talk
   package:com.android.talkback
   ```
7. I tried to launch the application, but it won't launch.  Also, I manually searched for it on my Pixel phone, but search does not find it.

   ```
   adb shell monkey -p com.android.talkback  1
     bash arg: -p
     bash arg: com.android.talkback
     bash arg: 1
   args: [-p, com.android.talkback, 1]
    arg: "-p"
    arg: "com.android.talkback"
    arg: "1"
   data="com.android.talkback"
   ** No activities found to run, monkey aborted.
   ```

"adb shell am start" didn't work either:

```
adb shell am start com.android.talkback
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] pkg=com.android.talkback }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.android.talkback }
```

Any ideas of where to go from here?  I'm stumped.  If I can get this to work, there's a lot of people who
may be helped.